# How is the RBG value in a STFT spectrogram related to the STFT information?

Tags: audio, rgb

The STFT spectrogram generated by `librosa` looks like this: [image: STFT.png].

I'm wondering how is the STFT information encoded in the RGB values?

Comment: output of a fft call is an array of complex numbers ... array element 0 stores the data for frequency zero and is commonly called the DC bias ...  each subsequent array element is the next frequency ... on each array element you calculate the magnitude from the complex number ... then typically you map the magnitude to color in your visualization

Comment: @ScottStensland I'm wondering how is the Fourier transformed numpy array mapped to the colormap values in the image. For example, If I use python's `X = librosa.stft(x)` and then I use `librosa.display.specshow(X)`. How is this `X` mapped to the figure it generated.

Comment: I use golang so not familiar with librosa ... as per https://github.com/librosa/librosa to quote : ...  Please direct non-development questions and discussion topics to our web forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/librosa